# Release Apk is not installing in Honor 6X-BLN-L22

Tags: android, performance, android-studio, android-7.0-nougat, huawei-mobile-services

I am trying to install release Apk(apk shared using whatsapp), it is working on moto and lenovo but not in Honor 6X-BLN-L22 
When tring to install it is going to settings page to asking to enable/allow install from unknown sources but it is enabled

```
 minSdkVersion 19
 targetSdkVersion 29
```

Comment: Please provide more info, like the method you are using to install, whats the error?

Comment: @RahulShukla It is going to settings page to enable allow install but it was enabled and again it is going to same page

Comment: You mean allow install from Unknown/Untrusted Sources?

Comment: @RahulShukla yes, it is enabled